Assignment inside of classes always uses broad types
So I was trying to make something unrelated to the problem, and came upon a weird thing in TS. If I create a type for example:
type A = "A" | "B" | "C";
type C = {
  variable: A;
}

I can create an object of type C while providing the value of variable with a string literal "A" like so:
const OBJ: C = {
    variable: "A"
}

But when I create a class implementing C I have to do "A" as A, "A" as "C" or "A" as const when assigning variable default value;
class O implements C {
    variable = "A"; // throws error `type string is not assignable to type A`
}

Why is that? Is  = "A" inside of classes treated differently?
TS Playground link

implements clauses only check types, they don't provide context.  So class O implements C { variable = "A" } behaves very much like class O { variable = "A" }, and TS infers just string for "A" unless you tell it you want something else (e.g., with as const).  Nobody really likes this behavior; people expect implements to provide context, but efforts to implement such changes to the language have hit other problems so they never did it. See the linked q/a for more information.  (You'd have the same problem if you wrote const o = {variable: "A"}; const obj: C = o;)
